# Could not set unknown property 'mainClass' for extension 'application

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm using Gradle version 6.1 in my project.

The **build.gradle** for the project is given below :

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

application {
    mainClass = 'com.mytestproject.Main'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

group 'com.mytestproject'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

But when I run this command `./gradlew assemble`, it is giving me error given below :

```
./gradlew assemble

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/com/myproject/build.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'JavaTestProject'.
> Could not set unknown property 'mainClass' for extension 'application' of type org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.DefaultJavaApplication.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 484ms
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modify **build.gradle** to this :

```
apply plugin: "application"

mainClassName = "com.mytestproject.Main"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

group 'com.mytestproject'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Run this commmand : `./gradlew build`

Comment: But why is that? I was following docs and got that error: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: @Daniel Cheung; the documentation you link to is for the current Gradle version, which on this day is 6.4.1. You may be using an older version of Gradle, e.g. in version 6.1 the property name is `mainClassname` (https://docs.gradle.org/6.1/userguide/application_plugin.html)

Comment: @C0deAttack Thanks, I didn't realize this was changed across versions.

Comment: @C0deAttack: Just in case anyone stumbles over this as I did In 6.1. the correct property name is mainClassName not mainClassname ...

Answer (score 2):

You could try this (based off [the source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/internal/DefaultJavaApplication.java)):

```
application {
    setMainClassName("some.package.Main")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually just modifying the `application` block to

```
application {
    mainClassName = 'com.mytestproject.Main'
}
```

does the same thing.

The problem seems to be that there used to be a `mainClass` attribute on the `org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.DefaultJavaApplication` class, but it later got renamed to `mainClassName`, rendering previous tutorials invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There was a deprecation introduced in 6.4. It went from:

```
 application {
   mainClassName = "com.foo.bar.FooBar"
 }
```

To:

```
 application {
   mainClass.set("com.foo.bar.FooBar")
 }
```

The Docs:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaApplication.html#getMainClassName--